# How to change react native APK name

Tags: react-native, apk

I am new to react native. And I had generated react native APK last time. that time my package.json look like this. means my apk name is = NasDigitalApp

```
"name": "NasDigitalApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
```

so my question is. can I change that name to like any other name lets say ABC and then generate same apk file. means by changing this name can APK name change or I have to do some other stuff like creating new project by new name. and then copy paste code in that and then. generate apk???

Answer (score 0):

Access strings.xml file and change the value. It's located at ../android/app/src/main/res/values

[image: change app name]